# c - can't solve Invalid read of size 1 on a client-server program

Tags: c, server, client, valgrind

client and server exchange messages by sending structures of this type:

```
typedef struct {
    op_t     op;   
    char sender[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
} message_hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    char receiver[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
    unsigned int   len;  
} message_data_hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    message_data_hdr_t  hdr;
    char               *buf;
} message_data_t;

typedef struct {
    message_hdr_t  hdr;
    message_data_t data;
} message_t;
```

the messages exchanged between client and server arrive correctly and execution proceeds but valgrind returns error:

```
==4179== Invalid read of size 1
==4179==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4179==    by 0x50B84D2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1643)
==4179==    by 0x50BFF25: printf (printf.c:33)
==4179==    by 0x10A122: threadF (main.c:151)
==4179==    by 0x4E436DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==4179==    by 0x517C88E: clone (clone.S:95)
==4179==  Address 0x5452134 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4179==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4179==    by 0x109B2B: readData (connections.h:103)
==4179==    by 0x109C17: readMsg (connections.h:134)
==4179==    by 0x10A0B0: threadF (main.c:146)
==4179==    by 0x4E436DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==4179==    by 0x517C88E: clone (clone.S:95)
```

this is how I fill the structure in the server in the readData();
you can consider readn as read.

```
#define SYSCALL(r,c,msg) \
    if((r=c)==-1) {perror(msg);

//other reads and writes
msg->data.buf=malloc(msg->data.hdr.len*sizeof(char));
SYSCALL(notused,readn(fd,msg->data.buf,msg->data.hdr.len*sizeof(char)),"read_data_buf");            
if(notused==0){
    return -1;
}
```

and i get error when i do the printf on main.c:151

```
printf("BODY: %s\n",msg->data.buf);
```

Comment: Given that it's `strlen()` and you're printing `msg->data.buf`, the chances are high that you've not null-terminated the string and therefore the printing code is reading out of bounds, triggering the Valgrind warning.  You could use `%.*s` in the format and then pass an `int` value saying how long the data in `msg->data.buf` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably

```
msg->data.buf=malloc(msg->data.hdr.len*sizeof(char));
SYSCALL(notused,readn(fd,msg->data.buf,msg->data.hdr.len*sizeof(char)),"read_data_buf");
```

must be

```
msg->data.buf=malloc(msg->data.hdr.len + 1);
SYSCALL(notused,readn(fd,msg->data.buf,msg->data.hdr.len),"read_data_buf");            
msg->data.buf[msg->data.hdr.len] = 0;
```

to add place for the ending null character and set it

**However** are you sure `msg->data.buf` is a printable string ? How do you encode your structs during the exchanges ?

---

Again `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, it is useless to multiply by it

Answer (score 1):

According to this message

```
==4179==  Address 0x5452134 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
```

you have allocated 4 bytes.

Your `printf` call

```
printf("BODY: %s\n",msg->data.buf);
```

expects to find a string terminated with `\0`

Probably the bytes you read with `SYSCALL(notused,readn(...` do not contain a `'\0'` within these 4 bytes, so `strlen` reads the next byte after the end of the allocated memory.

One option to solve this would be to allocate one byte more and append `'\0'` to the received data.